# Help understanding accumulation point proposition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A number $a ∈ K$ is an accumulation point of the sequence $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$
if and only if, for all $ε > 0$ and for all $N ∈ \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n > N$ such that $|a_ {n} −a| < ε$.

Does this imply that $a$ is a limit for $a_{ n }$? I'm asking this because of the similarity to the definition of the limit of a sequence.
And could something similar to $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda a_{n}=\lambda \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}$ be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are similar but not the same. The definition of the limit is stronger: given any $\epsilon>0$:

- The definition of the *accumulation point* only requires $a_n$ to be closer to $a$ than $\epsilon$ for *infinitely many* $n$.
- The *limit* definition requires $a_n$ to be closer to $a$ than $\epsilon$ for *all but finitely many* $n$.

You can see the difference on the sequence $(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots)$: it has no limit but has two accumulation points: $-1$ and $1$.

However, if a sequence has a limit $a$, it then has one and only accumulation point, which is also $a$.

And, yes, if $a$ is the accumulation point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then $\lambda a$ is an accumulation point of $(\lambda a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. (Try to prove it!) However, if $a$ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)$ and $b$ is an accumulation point of $(b_n)$, then $a+b$ does *not* need to be an accumulation point of $(a_n+b_n)$. (Try to find a counterexample.)

**Note**: I presume $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, although we could do the same with subsets of any normed space (e.g. $(\mathbb R^n, ||\cdot||)$).

Comment: +1. Caution: Some textbooks define that $a$ is an  accumulation point of a $set$ $S=\{a_n: n\in\Bbb N\} $ iff every neighborhood of $a$ contains some $b\in S$ with $b\ne a$. This is different from the meaning of an accumulation point of a $sequence$.

Comment: There is another link between accumulation points and limits. $a$ is an accumulation point of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ if and only if there is a subsequence $(a_{i_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (for some strictly increasing sequence of indices $(i_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$). In my above example, all even members of the sequence have the limit of $1$ and all odd members of the sequence have the limit of $-1$.